# How to export Flutter project for web hosting

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have developed a web app using Flutter in Android Studio IDE, and have enabled Flutter Web from the Flutter console. In Android Studio, I am able to run the app and use Chrome(web) as my target device; and the app runs well.

Can anyone advice what is the next step to export this to a web hosting service? Like PorkBun. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this command in the terminal:

```
flutter build web
```

It will compile your project for the web, then you should see a generated files under `[your_project]/build/web`

Upload the contents of the `web` folder to the root folder of your hosting service. The main page `index.html` should run your app.

Comment: Hey Ali, this worked! Thanks for the reply, I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer did the required, please give it 'upvote' and mark as 'accepted', to help others find the correct answer.

Comment: I have accepted the answer; but I'm unfortunately unable to upvote your comment.